# Таймер и API Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, api, telegram, бот

Я не до конца понимаю принцип работы запросов на API Telegram и хочу поинтересоваться у знатоков:

Например, пользователь отправил боту /start и бот ответил не сразу же, а через секунду.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что все запросы встают в очередь у API Telegram и не работают параллельно, например 3 запроса от разных пользователей будут отправлены обратно клиенту в зависимости от очереди?

Другими словами, например 1 клиент вызвал у бота функцию, которая занимает 1 минуту у скрипта, а 2 клиент вызвал функцию, которая занимает 1 секунду. Второму клиенту придёт ответ, когда придёт ответ первому ? Так получается ?

Comment: Когда вы ответите, тогда и придёт. Отправляйте долгие задачи в отдельный поток/процесс на выполнение, чтобы не блокировать основной поток вашей программы, и всё будет параллельненько

Comment: для каждого пользователя создается отдельный экземпляр бота

Answer (score 2):

каждое сообщение или действие в боте пользователя запускает скрипт на вашем хостинге. точно так же как и при просмотре веб страниц, разные люди запускают одну и ту же страницу, но она выполняется каждому своя параллельно, а не последовательно.

сам бот отдает и принимает действия мгновенно, а вот будет ваш скрипт на секунду или на минуту бота не волнует. он запустил несколько скриптов на вашем хостинге и они параллельно работают

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого пользователя запросы обрабатываются асинхронно. Но все зависит от того какую библиотеку Вы используете. Рекомендую aiogram/